# How many entries can be specified in the sendmail SMART_HOST config line?

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

CentOS | Sendmail

I have the following line in my sendmail.mc file:

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`relay:[1.1.1.1]:[2.2.2.2]')
```

My understanding is that sendmail will always smarthost to 1.1.1.1 and then fail-over to using 2.2.2.2 if necessary.

Can I specify a third entry here? For example:

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`relay:[1.1.1.1]:[2.2.2.2]:[3.3.3.3]')
```

What are the limits on how many entries I can specify here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the $#relay mailer definition, you will see for example that it is defined as:

```
Mrelay,         P=[IPC], F=mDFMuXa8, S=EnvFromSMTP/HdrFromSMTP, R=MasqSMTP, E=\r\n, L=2040,
                T=DNS/RFC822/SMTP,
                A=TCP $h
```

So your question effectively becomes: *Can $h be a colon separated list, and if yes, for how many hosts?*  To which the bat book replies in page 739:

> Beginning withV8 sendmail, $h (possibly as returned by the parse rule
>   set 0) can be a colon-separated list of hosts. The sendmail program
>   attempts to connect to each in turn, left to right:
>
> A=TCP hostA:hostB:hostC
>
> Here, it tries to connect to hostA first. If that
>   fails, it next tries hostB, and so on. As usual, trying a host means
>   trying its MX records first, or its A or AAAA record if there are no
>   MX records.

For the actual limit one would have to look at the sendmail sources to verify if any exists.

There is second argument implied in `A=TCP $h` which is omitted and this is the port number (assumed by default to be 25). You can have a host list and a single port, but I am not sure whether (or how) you can have a host list with a different listening port for incoming connections for each host on the list. For such an elaborate and tricky setup I would write another delivery agent that could make use of this.

Comment: Thanks. So it sounds like at there very least there isn't a hard-set limit of ONLY two, right?  Especially since the bat book would reference "hostC".